# Taping drywall and cementboard butted together

Tags: drywall, joints, cement-board, tape

When taping cementboard butted against drywall, is it better to use drywall (paper/mesh) tape with joint compound or cementboard mesh tape with thinset?

Comment: Will there be tile over the seam?

Comment: As Matthew asks it makes a difference I like to overlap tile onto drywall or Sheetrock to reduce cracking at a joint.

Comment: @Matthew yes, tile over the seam

Comment: Actually, somewhere it will and somewhere it won't (cabinets)

Answer (score 1):

Since you will put tile over the seam and also, I assume, thinset you should use screws and mesh made for concrete board.

The cement board and thinset may contain things which reduce efficacy of typical drywall screws, compound, and tape. Don't tape the seam until you're installing the tile.

Behind the cabinets you can use standard compound.